# Two projections are unitary equivalent and commute will give us self adjoint unitary equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am reading Jones famous paper **"index for subfactors"** recently. And I met some questions in the reading. Here is the link for the paper:https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/bf01389127.

I got stuck on Lemma 4.1.7 right now. To be more specific, I am not so sure how he get that $ue_iu^*=e_j$ and $ue_ju^*=e_i$ at the same time. We know that if $p\sim q$ in a finite von Neumann algebra $M$, then $p=uqu^*$ for some $u\in U(M)$. However, this will only give us $ue_iu^*=e_j$ and $u^*e_ju=e_i$. So I think we may need something more. I notice that in this case we always have $e_ie_j=e_je_i$. Hence, I guess we may may need this in the proof.

**My attempt:**

I am trying to prove the following **proposition**: If $p$, $q\in M$ are projections, $p\sim q$ and $pq=qp$, can we have a self adjoint unitary element $u\in U(M)_{sa}$ such that $p=uqu^*$. If the proposition is true, then Lemma 4.1.7 follows, but I couldn't prove the proposition right now.

**My question is**, Is the proposition above true? If it is true, how do we prove it? If it is not true, How do we prove Lemma 4.1.7 in the original paper?

Any help will be truly grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition is true for finite $M$.

From the fact that $pq=qp$ we get that $pq$ is a projection.

The following lemma is a particular case of Exercise 6.9.26 in Kadison-Ringrose II.

**Lemma.** Let $M$ be a finite von Neumann algebra, and $p,q$ be equivalent projections such that $pq=qp$. Then $p-pq$ is equivalent to $q-qp$.

By the Lemma, there exists a partial isometry $w$, with $w^*w=p-pq$, $ww^*=q-qp$. Note that $p-pq$ and $q-qp$ are orthogonal to each other. Now let
$$
u=w+w^*+[1-(p+ q-2pq)]. 
$$
Since $w^2=0$ and $w^*(1-p-q+2pq)=w(1-p-q+2pq)=0$, we have
$$
u^*u=u^2=ww^*+w^*w+1-p-q+2pq=1.
$$ As $M$ is finite, $u^*u=1$ implies that $u$ is a unitary (or one computes $uu^*$ directly). Finally, using that $w^*p=w^*(q-qp)p=0$,
$$
up=wp+pqp=w(p-pq)+pq=(q-pq)w+pq=qu.
$$

---

*Proof of the Lemma.* If $p-pq\not\preceq q-pq$ by comparison there exists $z\in Z(M)$ with $z(q-pq)\prec z(p-pq)$. So there exists a proper subprojection $g\leq p-pq$ with $$z(q-pq)\sim g\leq (p-pq).$$
Now
$$
zp\sim zq=z(q-pq)+zpq\sim g+zpq\leq z(p-pq)+zpq=zp.
$$
This shows that $zp\sim g+zpq$. As $g+zpq$ is a proper subprojection of $zp$ and $M$ is finite, we get a contradiction. So $z$ cannot exist, showing that $p-pq\preceq q-pq$. Exchanging roles we get the equivalence.

Comment: Thanks so much for the nice answer, I think it works.

Comment: But I think in the proof of Lemma 4.1.7, we consider the algebra $A_I$ where $I$ is a finite subset, so $A_I$ is a finite von Neumann algebra but not a factor, I wonder if the proposition still holds in this condition?

Comment: To be more specific, I hope this proposition works for finite dimensional von Neumann algebra, which is of course a finite von Neumann algebra but may not be a factor in general.

Comment: Yes. When you don't have a factor the proof is slightly more convoluted but still holds.

Comment: Would you like to give some hint when  we don't have a factor? I think in that case we can’t use comparison theorem if we don’t introduce a new projection $z$ in $P(Z(M))$. If we introduce the projection, I think the proof for the lemme won’t hold.

Comment: The proof is basically the same. I have edited it in.

Comment: I wonder why we can get $(−) \prec (−)$? We can always get $(−) \preceq (−)$ for sure by comparison theorem, but how do we make sure that the case $(−)\sim (−)$ won't happen when we have $−\not\preceq −$? It is a little confusing, I guess I might miss something.

Comment: If $z(q-pq)\prec z(p-pq)$ fails for all central $z$ then $p-pq\preceq q-pq$, which what we wanted to prove.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer!

Comment: Glad I could help!